# Listing all users from database, with multiple columns & ascending order

Tags: php, mysql, database, leaderboard

In short, a leaderboard.

The person with the highest coins wants to be listed, first. listing the top 10 only, based on the highest coin count joined with their username.

This lists the usernames, but not sure how to get their coins count, as well as ascend them in a top 10 formation.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM `users`");

echo '<table>';
while($rowtwo = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo    '<tr>
            <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color="red">'.$rowtwo['username'].'</td>
            </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Fixed this. <?php
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT `username`, `coins` FROM `users`");
 
 echo '<table>';
 while($rowtwo = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo  '<tr>
    <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color="red">'.$rowtwo['username'].' '.$rowtwo['coins'].'</td>
    </tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
 ?>

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT username FROM `users` ORDER BY coins DESC LIMIT 10
```

The `DESC` is important or else it will list coins in order of lowest to highest.  This also assumes that coin count is a column of `users`.  If it's not, you'll have to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Change the query to:

```
SELECT username FROM `users` ORDER BY `coins` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: You are welcome! Btw, why named you the record `$rowtwo` ? Wouldn't `$user` be a more descriptive variable name?